# Correctly way to restart passenger in Capistrano deploy file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, passenger

I am new on rails developing, my problem is: I have a server with virtual machines and during a Capistrano deployment, ngnix passenger doesn't restart.

[This example](https://nathanhoad.net/deploy-a-rails-app-on-passenger-with-capistrano) and [this](https://github.com/capistrano/passenger/issues/2) don't work for me. Anyone help me please!

Logs:

```
14915 pts/2    S+     0:00 tail -f -n 0 /home/deployer/parking/releases/20151013115625/log/production.log
14916 pts/2    S+     0:00 tail -f -n 0 /home/deployer/parking/releases/20151013115625/log/passenger.4324.log
14942 ?        Sl     0:00 Passenger RubyApp: /home/deployer/parking/releases/20151013115625/public (production
```

deploy.rb:

```
set :deploy_to, '/home/deployer/parking/'
set :passenger_port, 4324
set :passenger_in_gemfile, true
set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true




set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do

    end
  end

end


after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'

set :passenger_restart_command, 'passenger-config restart-app'
set :passenger_restart_options, -> { "#{deploy_to} --ignore-app-not-running" }
```

Comment: not working is detailed enough, please provide error log or tell us what going wrong and paste code what exactly you did in your deploy.rb

Comment: You don't have enough information here for anyone to know what might be going wrong. What is in your logs? What is in your browser window when you try to access it? Do you use Passenger with apache, nginx, or standalone? If apache or nginx, are you sure apache or nginx are running?

Comment: i will update, just one sec please

Comment: Updated, check it please